# Loop error for multiple conditions

Tags: ruby

I have this loop:

```
puts "Welcome to the Loop Practice Problems"
puts " Write a number between 1 and 10, but not 5 or else...."
ans = gets.chomp!
if ans < 1
  puts "Tf bruh bruh"
elsif ans > 10
  puts "Now you just playin"
elsif x == 5
  print "You wildin B"
else
  puts "Fosho that's all I require"
end
```

It doesn't run properly, and I'm trying to understand why. If you can help me with this, I'd appreciate it.

If you know a good site for practice problems, I'd love to try it. I checked out Coderbyte and Code Kata, but the way they're set up doesn't look right, and they don't have questions to solve for fundamentals.

Comment: You also have a typo in `elsif x==5` should be `elsif ans==5`

Comment: You don't have a loop.

Comment: Define what you mean by "run properly".

Comment: Is there any significance in using `print` just under the third branch?

Comment: You can start practicing ruby: 
 https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-ruby/lessons/

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you're not converting `ans` to a number, but you're comparing it to one. `ans` is going to be a string.

In Ruby, when you compare a number to a string, Ruby says that the two aren't equal:

```
"1" == 1
=> false
```

You can reproduce the problem with this code:

```
puts "Welcome to the Loop Practice Problems"
puts " Write a number between 1 and 10, but not 5 or else...."

ans=gets.chomp!
p ans
```

The `p` method will output an "inspected" version of that object, (it's the same as doing `puts ans.inspect`). This will show it wrapped in quotes, which indicates that it's a string.

You probably want to do this:

```
ans = gets.chomp!.to_i
```

The `to_i` method here will convert the number to an integer, and then your comparisons will work correctly.

Comment: And you probably want `chomp` (without `!`) since the bang variant might return `nil`.

Comment: @Stefan you probably do not want `chomp` at all, since `"1\n".to_i #⇒ 1` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert input string type object into integer type

```
ans = gets.chomp!.to_i #input string convert into integer.
if ans < 1
  puts "Tf bruh bruh"
elsif ans > 10
  puts "Now you just playin"
elsif x == 5
  print "You wildin B"
else
  puts "Fosho that's all I require"
end
```